# Is the mystic form stronger than SSJ3?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

We know as a fact that SSJ < SSJ2 < SSJ3 < SSG < SSB . But what about the mystic form that probably Gohan is going to recover? Is there any official info / evidence that shows how strong it is compared to the other forms?

Comment: You can't compare the form to determine who is stronger, what you can compare is by their base form. I think what you want to compare is the form's multiplier.

Comment: I didnt compare the form to determine who is stronger. But the same person with a particular form is stronger than the same person in another form. We do know that Goku SSJ < Goku SSJ2 < Goku SSJ3 < Goku SSG < Goku SSB . Which doesnt mean Vegeta SSJ2 < Goku SSJ3 for example. At one point it is said that Vegeta in SSJ2 surpassed Goku in SSJ3.

Comment: The answer to this is quite simple. When Gohan is in his ultimate state, he has access to his full potential power. Depding on what Gohan's maximum super Saiyan level is at a given time, Mysitc Gohan will be equal to that level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My take on this is that his "mystic" form is just him unleashing all his power without turning into a SSJ which puts some strain on his body / wastes some energy.

Basically even if he could go SSJ3 there is no need for that because he can bring all of that energy out in this "mystic" form without any side effects. So no matter how strong he becomes with this he does not need to transform (regarding the normal Saiyan transformation).

Now regarding the "god" transformation (if he ever reaches it), I'm not sure. Since we have a new kind of ki involved maybe he can not bring that out without transforming into a SSG but that is even more based on speculation.

In the end, Mystic form > all other normal SSJ forms because it enables him to draw out all energy without any side effects.

Answer (score 1):

> **SSJ2 < Mystic Form < SSJ3**

Mystic Form is Stronger than SSJ2.

Evidence:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkSsU7tO3Ew

Mystic Gohan was More Powerful than SSJ2 Goku or Vegeta during fight with Buu, But Buu after absorbing Gotenks(SSJ3) became stronger than Gohan.

Thus, Mystic form more powerful than SSJ2 but less than SSJ3.

---

**Another Evidence**

SSJ3 Goku was equally matched with Kid Buu.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aMPHOHX9Bc

Kid Buu was way much powerfull than of its any other form.

Gohan could only overpower Super Buu, But was easily defeated by Gotenks absorbed Super Buu.

Hence SSJ3 > Mystics Form

Comment: but Buu combined his own strength (which was over a SSJ2) with that of the SSJ3. It isnt the SSJ3 strength only who is fighting mystic Gohan

Comment: Fat Buu was strong enough to go toe to toe with a weakened SSJ3 Goku. However, Goku from the start couldn't win, despite being at near full power when he started. Gotenks SSJ3 was unable to really win against Super buu, who was roughly as powerful as Fat Buu. Gohan came along and overpowered Super Buu far more than SSJ3 Gotenks, and once they split inside and Super Buu Gotens absorbed downgraded to Super Buu Piccolo Absorbed, Goku decided there was no need to fuse with Gohan, SSJ3 Goku and Mystic Gohan could have won. Mystic Gohan seems to beat up Super Buu better than either SSJ3 Character.

Comment: @Ryan During Fight with Fat Buu SSJ3 Goku was onlying stalling Buu so that Trunks could find the Dragon Radar.

Comment: @Ryan "Gotenks SSJ3 was unable to really win against Super buu, who was roughly as powerful as Fat Buu." Actually that's wrong since Gotenks was overpowering buu, Till it absorbed them.

Comment: well if it isnt clear, and since aparently Gohan is going to recover his mystic form soon, may be Dragon Ball Super will give a definitive answer to this question. Or may be they will release a osm book which does. Particulary I dont see SSJ3 overpowering the mystic form, may be they are equal, Dragon Ball Z: Wrath of the Dragon rises more questions since there Goku SSJ3 defeats Hirudegarn when mystic Gohan couldnt, but that movie isnt canon and may be it just was the dragon technique and not his SSJ3 what allowed Goku to defeat it

Answer (score 0):

According to some spoilers appearing in a japanese magazine about the upcoming Dragon Ball Super episodes

> Gohan is able to hold his own against Super Saiyan Blue Goku in mystic form

Edit: 13/05/2017. After seeing Dragon Ball Super episode 90th

> It's quite questionable if Gohan can hold his own against Super Saiyan Blue

Answer (score 0):

Well SSJ3 Goku Was Slightly injured but was still equal to Fat Buu but Mystic Gohan Overpowered Super Buu which was a little stronger than Fat Buu since its Evil and Fat Buu combined.But lost to Buutenks which had the power of at least two SSJ3's which does kinda make Mystic a little stronger than SSJ3 cuz its not rlly a multiplier it just unleashes the energy he can use with all SSJ forms he has (Including Base) combined,without using a lot of energy and stress and Kid Buu shouldnt have been the strongest form out of all Buu (Gohan Absorbed) should have been since its two SSJ3's Combined with mystic and Fat Buu was all Kai's absorbed so he should have gained there power too but they never returned after kid buu's demise so rlly Kid buu should be around a little less than SSJ3 the only reason he overpowered Goku was because his moves were unpredictable since he attacked without thought so That might have been a reason :)

Answer (score 0):

Some people only see Mystic form as a transformation. It is not. The thing is the Spiritual Gods like Kami, Yama, Kai, Grand Kai, Supreme Kai, God of Something, God Superintendent, Universal God (Dragon God Zalama) are Ranks that can pass pressure on the lower Rank very easy.

Since Gohan is a Mortal, below Kami rank, his potential can be opened by Namekian Great Elder (Kami rank) and even further by the old Supreme Kai (percentage wise). After training, Gohan of course could have gone to the Namekian great elder again, but that guy is dead. Anyway, Gohan unlocked the SSJ2 Stage. When he was a kid he was pretty strong, but he kinda got weaker in his teenage years. He was weaker than SSJ2 Goku and Vegeta. But still, after Dabura fight, he got a little bit stronger again because of the near even fight. Afterward, he kinda was on the level of the cell games. After training and unlocking his potential on the Planet of Supreme Kai, he basically absorbed the SSJ1 and SSJ2 states which makes him put out even more energy that otherwise would have been wasted and he does not get any strain that is accompanied by the SSJ1 and SSJ2 state. He is basically his base state with the power level of the maximum SSJ2 state. So in a way, he is stronger than Goku SSJ3 because he doesn't waste energy that much and has no strain. It's like the Saiyan God state. Every possible transformation tabs into your potential.

So lets make this simple:
SSJ1 < SSJ1-Mystic=SSJ2 < SSJ2-Mystic=SSJ3 < SSJ3-Mystic=SSJ4 < SSJ4Mystic=SSG < SSG-Mystic=SSB < SSB-Mystic etc etc.

The Mystic state is basically the transformed strength into the base form which will in turn be always better or equal to the next transformed state. In Gohan's case, it is stronger than SSJ3 but not as strong against Buu that absorbed so many characters. This mystic state basically is the true path to godhood.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's the thing: unlike the Super Saiyan forms, Mystic doesn't universally multiply every person's power by the same amount. The increase a martial artist gets from Mystic is completely dependent on how much hidden potential is within that person. If Umigame and Goten were at the same power level and both went through the Mystic ritual, for example, Goten would receive a way stronger boost, as he's a martial artist and a half-Saiyan.

If we're talking GOHAN'S Mystic boost, however... it actually is stronger than Super Saiyan 3. We know this because when Gotenks fought Super Buu, his Super Saiyan 3 form was stronger than Goku's, meaning his base form must have also exceeded Goku's. And we know for a fact that Goku's base form was stronger than Gohan's. Meaning:

Base form
Gohan (weakest) --> Goku (mid) --> Gotenks (strongest)

When Gotenks fought Super Buu as a Super Saiyan 3, Gotenks was stronger, but the strength difference between the two wasn't that great-- Buu even manages to hurt Gotenks a bit, albeit nothing too major. Yet when GOHAN fought Super Buu with Mystic, Gohan's strength exceeded Super Buu's by a mile. Therefore, Mystic provided the greater power boost, as it took the Saiyan with the weakest base form (of the three I mentioned) and made him stronger than Gotenks at Super Saiyan 3.